# Can't create jdbc realm in Glassfish 4

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, glassfish

I am trying to create a jdbc realm in Glassfish 4.0 but it gives me the following error.

> Creation of Authrealm realmforsuggestboard failed. java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error: Invalid control flag, REQUİRED java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error: Invalid control flag, REQUİRED

I tried to ping the connection pool and it works fine.

Here is the log output.

> [2014-07-01T10:21:44.674+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [realm.loaded.successfully] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm] [tid: _ThreadID=190 _ThreadName=admin-listener(8)] [timeMillis: 1404199304674] [levelValue: 800] [[
>     SEC1115: Realm [realmformyboard] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm] successfully created.]]
>
> [2014-07-01T10:21:44.679+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [org.glassfish.admingui] [tid: _ThreadID=37 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1404199304679] [levelValue: 1000] [[
>     RestResponse.getResponse() gives FAILURE.  endpoint = 'http://localhost.com:4848/management/domain/configs/config/default-config/security-service/auth-realm'; attrs = '{classname=com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm, name=realmformyboard, property=jaas-context=jdbcRealm:datasource-jndi=jdbc/myboard:user-table=users:user-name-column=email:password-column=password:group-table=groups:group-table-user-name-column=email:group-name-column=group_name:digestrealm-password-enc-algorithm=SHA-256:, target=default-config}']]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem was locale language of JVM. When i add the following properties to JVM Options in Glassfish, everything begun to work properly.

> -Duser.language=en
>
> -Duser.region=US